# How to format output of shell script from one column to multiple column

Tags: shell, unix

The output of my shell script is as follows(please find the attached image)

```
workflow_Name1
Succeeded
Tue May 19 11:15:33 2015
workflow_Name2
Succeeded
Wed Jun 10 18:00:21 2015
```

I want this to be changed to

```
workflow_Name1 :-Succeeded :-Tue May 19 11:15:33 2015
workflow_Name2 :-Succeeded :-Wed Jun 10 18:00:21 2015
```

Following is the script I am using. Could you please let me know how to achieve this.

```
#!/bin/bash
# source $HOME/.bash_profile

output=/home/infaprd/cron/output.lst

sqlplus -s user/test@dev <<EOF >$output   # Capture output from SQL
set linesize 55 pages 500
spool output_temp.lst;
set head off;
select sysdate from dual;
set head on;
spool off;
EOF

for name in workflow_Name1 workflow_Name2; do
  pmcmd getworkflowdetails -Repository ${name}
done |
grep -e "Workflow:" -e "Workflow run status:" -e "End time:" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1 |

sed -e 's/ *$//' >> $output
mail -s "Output - `date '+%d-%m-%y'`" akhil@gmail.com <$output
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `awk`

```
awk '{getline a;getline b; if($0) printf "%-s\n", $0 " :-" a " :-" b}'
```

Output:

```
workflow_Name1 :-Succeeded :-Tue May 19 11:15:33 2015
workflow_Name2 :-Succeeded :-Wed Jun 10 18:00:21 2015
```

You can also use `sed` to accomplish this task:

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/ :-/g'
```

Comment: Thanks Rakholiya, the sed's output is coming in a single line. How to print the second workflow in second line.

Comment: have a look at http://ideone.com/AJZANa. `sed` output is also the same as the awk output.

Comment: Thanks Rakholiya, Appreciate your help. The issue is, when writing to the file, its coming as single row. Otherwise in the command prompt, it comes as a two rows as expected. Any pointers.

Comment: @AkhilNarayananNair, when I am trying to redirect to output to a file using `sed 'N;N;s/\n/ \:\-/g' inputfile > outputfile`, output is coming in two separate lines for me.

Comment: I am sending the final file as an email. In the email it is a single line. Do I need to do any formatting for email.

Comment: Write the email in plain text format instead of html format. Writing in html format might be giving an error to you. Else check if break tag work (append it to the outputfile by replacing \n with <br> i). I would prefer to write it in plain text. BTW what is wrong in using `awk` if that gives a correct output

Comment: Sorry Rakholiya, even the awk output in the email comes as a single line.

Comment: Then best way I can think of is sending the mail written in plain text, not in html form